How to Run NetLogo Headless Without a Pre-Existing .nlogo File (Starting from .nls File)?
I would like to set up a fully headless NetLogo workflow, that doesn't require me to open the GUI to create the initial .nlogo file. Everything I've been able to find through searching requires a .nlogo file to already exist as created by the GUI. Is it possible to create a .nlogo file from a .nls file without a GUI? Or to run headless mode just from the .nls without a .nlogo file? I am using OpenJDK 11 and NetLogo 6.4.0 on Mac OS Sonoma.
I have looked at the BehaviorSpace documentation, but all the headless examples use pre-existing .nlogo files.
I tried to create a minimal example using a .nls file and a .java file:
minimal.nls (runs correctly when plugged into the GUI):
globals []

to go
  print "Hello World!"
  tick
end


Minimal.java:
import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Minimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeadlessWorkspace workspace = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();
        try {
            // Read NetLogo code from the file
            String netlogoCode = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("minimal.nls")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            // Print the NetLogo code for verification
            System.out.println("NetLogo code:");
            System.out.println(netlogoCode);

            // Open the workspace
            try {
                workspace.openString(netlogoCode);
                System.out.println("NetLogo code loaded successfully.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error loading NetLogo code:");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            // Run the simulation
            try {
                workspace.command("go");
                System.out.println("Simulation ran successfully.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error running 'go' command:");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("An error occurred while reading the NetLogo file:");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            // Close the workspace and handle InterruptedException
            try {
                workspace.dispose();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Optionally, restore the interrupted status
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}


Expected result:
NetLogo code:
globals []

to go
  print "Hello World!"
  tick
end

NetLogo code loaded successfully.
Hello world!
Simulation ran successfully.

Actual result:
NetLogo code:
globals []

to go
  print "Hello World!"
  tick
end

NetLogo code loaded successfully.
Error running 'go' command:
Nothing named GO has been defined. at position 33 in
    at org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception(Fail.scala:27)
    at org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception(Fail.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception(Fail.scala:23)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseStatement(ExpressionParser.scala:151)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$apply$1(ExpressionParser.scala:32)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseStatements(ExpressionParser.scala:44)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.apply(ExpressionParser.scala:32)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.parseProcedure(NetLogoParser.scala:47)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.parseProcedure$(NetLogoParser.scala:29)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.parseProcedure(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.$anonfun$basicParse$1(NetLogoParser.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse(NetLogoParser.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse$(NetLogoParser.scala:15)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.basicParse(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:26)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd$(FrontEnd.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:47)
    at org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileMoreCode(Compiler.scala:85)
    at org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileMoreCode(Compiler.scala:100)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.invokeCompiler(Evaluator.scala:160)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.evaluateCommands(Evaluator.scala:20)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluating.command(Evaluating.scala:80)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluating.command$(Evaluating.scala:79)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceScala.command(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:25)
    at Minimal.main(Minimal.java:30)

How can I run a NetLogo model in headless mode starting from a .nls file or source code without needing to create a .nlogo file in the GUI? Am I doing something wrong, or does this functionality not exist/do I have to use the GUI to create the model file?

You do need to have an .nlogo file, but it doesn't have to be one you made in the GUI; you can generate the .nlogo file yourself, it's a textual format.

Thanks for the response. I am unclear on how to generate a .nlogo file complete with headers, it seems like pasting even a working .nlogo file's contents into a new file does not work. Can you explain or point me to an explanation of how to generate a .nlogo file from scratch using CLI only? Thanks!

I promise you .nlogo files are just text files. There is literally no way for NetLogo to know whether a given .nlogo file was created by the GUI or by some other means. Perhaps your .nlogo file is fine and you're doing something wrong in the code you're using to run it? You've only said "does not work", which isn't enough detail to help troubleshoot.

Another possibility that whatever exactly you are doing when you "past[e] even a working .nlogo file's contents into a new file" is somehow altering the file. If the file was literally identical, then NetLogo would have no way to know the difference. Consider using a program that can compare files byte-by-byte to find out what difference you are introducing.

Thanks for the correction. I was unable to reproduce the copy/paste issue. Is there a reference for the structure of .nlogo files somewhere?

yes, https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/File-%28.nlogo%29-and-Widget-Format (but I don't know how up to date it is, I haven't been involved with the project for ages)
